# Truncating HTML 'Browse' filename

Tags: html, css, forms, truncate

I have a separate PHP file containing the logic and form code for an upload script I written.  I have included it into a div on my admin page and I have it set to float: right.  However, when I select a file with an exceptionally long filename, it pushes the entire form away from the right hand side of the page and I wish to be able to truncate it.  I have tried variants of overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis but can't get it to shorten as it's a part of the HTML browse form.

e.g.
Original:
01123581321345589144.jpg
Truncated:
0112358...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width on the input field? I know that works in Chrome but not sure about the other browsers.

Comment: -facepalm-  This worked for the div container -- many thanks.